# CSS - Sticky & Flexible Fixed Right Button

Tags: css, sticky

I have a very big problem to make an sticky fixed button on the right of the page, this button will be a dynamic text with different languages.

So, there is my code and try to use many words to test and the button must stick on the right :

```
<a href="#" class="button">Contact us</a>

a.button {
    background: #43515a url("http://www.aristaofrotorua.co.nz/rotorua-accommodation/images/email.jpg") no-repeat 88% center;
        font-family: "Myriad Pro";
        font-size: 17px;
        color: white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 0 10px;
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        position: absolute; 
        top: 109px;
        right: 0;
        /*width: 136px;*/
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 45px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        transform: rotate(-90deg);

}
```

[Myfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atatos/nLXGS/2/)

Comment: Try giving negative right value - right: -35px;

Comment: Do you mean like this? [http://jsfiddle.net/nLXGS/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/nLXGS/4/)

Comment: @AbhayKumar That's not resolving the problem :(

Comment: @Adam you just add a padding to button, no that not what i want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve your issue if you change the default `transform-origin` property which is `50% 50%` to `100% 100%`.

> The transform-origin CSS property lets you modify the origin for
>   transformations of an element. For example, the transform-origin of
>   the rotate() function is the centre of rotation.

[see here for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

That means that by default your element rotates around it's center (50% form left and 50% from top). So when you change the content, the element's width changes too, moving the origin of the `rotate` property. So you need to set the transform origin to the right bottom (100% 100%) which isn't moving according to the content in your case. so the transform origin doesn't move either.

CSS to add :

```
-webkit-transform-origin:100% 100%;
-moz-transform-origin:100% 100%;
transform-origin:100% 100%;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/nLXGS/11/)**

```css
body {
  background: #ededed;
}
a.button {
  background: #43515a url("http://www.aristaofrotorua.co.nz/rotorua-accommodation/images/email.jpg") no-repeat 88% center;
  font-family: "Myriad Pro";
  font-size: 17px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 10px;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 109px;
  right: 0;
  /*width: 136px;*/
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 45px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Conta sdsdsd s ct us lkjcvgf</a>
```

Comment: @3rror404 Almost in fact no need to change any values, just set the transform origin to right bottom http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/nLXGS/11/

Comment: Since `transform: rotate()` isn't supported in ie8 I'd say that's irreleveant

Comment: @web-tiki Can understand why it's working with just adding this transform-origin ??

Comment: @kach I updated my answer, hope you understand better.